# How to remove duplicates based on the last few characters in a particular column?

Tags: sorting, uniq

I have a file with multiple columns but I want to remove duplicates of the last 8 characters in the first column only. There is an example below:

```
 AJCBK:1:1106:16747:8632_1:N:0:AGCTTCAGTTGTGTGG +   Gene    0   Sequence    Score   0
 AJCBK:1:1109:14645:19987_1:N:0:AGCTTCAGTTGTGTGG    +   Gene    0   Sequence    Score   0
 AJCBK:1:1111:14232:8175_1:N:0:AGCTTCAGCTGCCCTT +   Gene    0   Sequence    Score   0
 AJCBK:1:2101:5753:25007_1:N:0:AGCTTCAGCTGCCCTT +   Gene    0   Sequence    Score   0
 AJCBK:1:2101:8971:7239_1:N:0:AGCTTCAGGGTATGGC  +   Gene    0   Sequence    Score   0
 AJCBK:1:2102:15618:28054_1:N:0:AGATTCAGTTGTGTGG    +   Gene    0   Sequence    Score   0
 AJCBK:1:2106:15389:25632_1:N:0:AGCTTCAGTTGTATCT    +   Gene    0   Sequence    Score   0
 AJCBK:1:2113:17273:8419_1:N:0:AGCTTCAGCTGCCCTT +   Gene    0   Sequence    Score   0
```

As you can see each line is different based on the first 23 characters so I cannot run uniq on the first column by itself. I want to remove all duplicates based on the last 8 character so it will look like this:

```
 AJCBK:1:1106:16747:8632_1:N:0:AGCTTCAGTTGTGTGG +   Gene    0   Sequence    Score   0
 AJCBK:1:1111:14232:8175_1:N:0:AGCTTCAGCTGCCCTT +   Gene    0   Sequence    Score   0
 AJCBK:1:2101:8971:7239_1:N:0:AGCTTCAGGGTATGGC  +   Gene    0   Sequence    Score   0
 AJCBK:1:2106:15389:25632_1:N:0:AGCTTCAGTTGTATCT    +   Gene    0   Sequence    Score   0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
gawk "{x=substr($1,length($1)-8,8); if (!seen[x]) {print $0}; seen[x]++}" data.txt
```

It takes the last 8 characters of field 1 into `x`, keep track of patterns in `seen`, and if it's a new pattern it will print the whole line, otherwise it prints nothing.

Comment: This is really neat. I didn't know such a thing existed. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Read your file line by line and then split it based on space. Take the first element of the split. This will be the element of first column. Now take last 8 characters of the first element. In python like language it will be as simple as:

```
last_eight = complete[-8::1]
```

In C if you want to obtain the same result; then you will have to use strtok to tokenise; then take the length of token and copy last 8 characters to some other variable. This will give you your comparison string.

After performing these steps; comparison should be trivial. You can store all these comparison string in an array and perform a brute force comparison. The index of array will be the line no. Whenever you find a duplicate you will know the line no by index number of array